# Prolog: Split a list of size N into two lists of known size K and N-K

Tags: list, split, prolog

I have a list of integers, Keys, and want to split it into two lists ListOfReqKeys and ListOfRewKeys as described in the title.

```
Keys =[1, 1, 3, 9, 1, 15]
ReqK = 3
ListOfReqKeys = [1, 1, 3], ListOfRewKeys = [9, 1, 15]
```

The length of those two lists is known, its ReqK and RewK respectively.

```
append(ListOfReqKeys, ListOfRewKeys, Keys),
atom_codes(At, ListOfReqKeys),
atom_number(At, ReqK).
```

Is there a built in predicate or a faster way of doing that?

Comment: Please give sample input and the desire output, along with a complete program that does (or attempts to do) what you want. Then please define what "better" means to you.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you for your comment...
Is this part of the code not enough in order for people to understand the question?

Comment: No, not really. I like to be able to run your code and see the results. Have a read of how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do you need an arbitrary ability to split, or is the list always split in half? If you want something to be *faster*, then narrowing the requirement can sometimes help.

Comment: Your code that has `append`, `atom_codes`, and `atom_number` seems to muddle what you're asking about. It's not clear to me what that code is for. Using your example values, `atom_codes(At, ListOfReqKeys)` would result in `At = '\001\001\003'`, and then `atom_number(At, ReqK)` would just fail since the atom bound to `At` doesn't represent a number.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, and sorry for the incomplete question.
Im really new to programming.
I should have specified that list keys is given and i need to produce ListOfReqKeys and ListOfRewKeys.

Comment: The code was not finished when i posted the question , but now it kinda is..
I can edit it in if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no splitting. There is only appending.

Splitting a list of length `N` into a prefix of length `K` will necessarily leave the suffix with length `N-K` - there's no need to measure / *create*<sup>1</sup> it so. It will just *be* so, by construction.

Thus,

```
split( K, L, A, B):-
   append( A, B, L),
   length(A, K).
```

Simple, isn't it. But wait, can it be improved upon? Without adding or removing anything from it? What else can we do with it?

<sup>1</sup><sub>hint: have you ever tried `length(X, 2)`? `length(X, N)`?</sub>

Comment: Thats what i needed..
Yeah i have tried it, it is satisfied when X is unified with a list of two terms.
Would switching the order of append and length make it better??
Intuitively it seems so but i cant explain why

Comment: yes, exactly! when append is first, it tries all ways of splitting the list, say for 5 elements it tries 0,5 ; 1,4; 2,3; 3,2; 4,1; 5,0 splits. but when length is first, and K is known, it generates the K-elements list of placeholders - the elements aren't known yet, but the length is (e.g. for K=2, [_A, _B]), and so append doesn't try all the combinations but works directly with the one we need  - we know we need K-long prefix!